# How can i save every move that was made "a, w, s, or d" to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I want to save every move 'char' to an array, and then call back all arrays to see the history

```cpp
cout << "===    Chose    ===" << endl;
cout << "Choose were to GO" << endl;
cout << "a, w, s, or d" << endl;
cout << endl;
cin >> Сhoice_1;

if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'a')
{
    cout << "You made a step to the left" << endl;
    value1 = -1;
    if (value1 < 0) break;
}
if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 's')
{
    cout << "You made a step back" << endl;
    value1 = -1;
    if (value1 < 0) break;
}
if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'w')
{
    cout << "You made a step foward" << endl;
    value1 = -1;
    if (value1 < 0) break;
}
if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'd')
{
    cout << "You made a step to the right" << endl;
    value1 = -1;
    if (value1 < 0) break;
}
if (LifeOptionMain <= 0)
{
    value1 = -1;
    if (value1 < 0) break;
}
```

I tried for loop

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    move[i + 1];
    move[i] = Сhoice_1;
}
```

but all elements are only one symbol, last input symbol, if last was a then output will be
a
a
a
....
what am I doing wrong??? please help.

Comment: Considering you set `value1` to `-1` immediately afterward checking if `value` is less than `0` seems a tad unnecessary. You could just `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run into trouble with the length of your array, but this would work.

```
char moveArray[1024];
int moveArrayIndex = 0;

...

cin >> Сhoice_1;
moveArray[moveArrayIndex++] = Choice_1;
moveArray[moveArrayIndex] = 0;  // This makes it a printable string.

...
```

The problem with this is that you're flow off the end of your array if there are more moves than you made space for. A different data structure would be safer.

```
std::vector<char> moveArray;

cin >> Choice_1;
moveArray.push_back(Choice_1);
```

However, this is probably using techniques you're not ready for yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks a lot, if anyone needs a solution to a similar problem, I'll leave the code. I apologize in advance since this is just a study task.

function #1

```
do
            {
                cout << "=== Make a move ===" << endl;
                cout << "===    Chose    ===" << endl;
                cout << "Choose were to GO" << endl;
                cout << "a, w, s, or d" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cin >> Сhoice_1;

                if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'a')
                {
                    cout << "You made a step to the left" << endl;
                    value1 = -1;
                    move.push_back(Сhoice_1);
                    if (value1 < 0) break;
                }
                if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 's')
                {
                    cout << "You made a step back" << endl;
                    value1 = -1;
                    move.push_back(Сhoice_1);
                    if (value1 < 0) break;
                }
                if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'w')
                {
                    cout << "You made a step foward" << endl;
                    value1 = -1;
                    move.push_back(Сhoice_1);
                    if (value1 < 0) break;
                }
                if (tolower(Сhoice_1) == 'd')
                {
                    cout << "You made a step to the right" << endl;
                    value1 = -1;
                    move.push_back(Сhoice_1);
                    if (value1 < 0) break;
                }
                if (LifeOptionMain <= 0)
                {
                    value1 = -1;
                    if (value1 < 0) break;
                }
                return Сhoice_1;
```

function #2

```
void Move_History()
    {
        for (char i : move)
        {
            cout << "You made a move - : " << i << ":";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```